# Is the macbook retina's soldered RAM in any way faster than typical RAM?

Tags: memory, macbook-pro

You would think it would make some kind of difference...

Comment: It will be interesting if anyone has actually done a measurement to show that this controller is faster or slower than [SO-DIMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM). I would expect the opposite - no measurable difference with only the CPU/memory controller/cache and RAM speed itself making any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. Access times might be faster by a handful of picoseconds, since the electrical impulses would travel a slightly shorter distance by taking away the circuitry in the socket. However that distance is dwarfed by the variance in placement of the RAM on the logic board — sometimes it's closer to the CPU, sometimes farther away.

The predominant factors for speed of RAM are the clock speed and bit width, not the physical layout.

Answer (score 1):

Faster, probably not.  Otherwise the difference is twofold, IMO.

- With no physical RAM slots, they can more closely integrate the
  components to save on space and make a thinner machine.
- From a commercial perspective, you have to pay up-front for more RAM, as
  you cannot add more later on (you have to buy a new computer).